# Combining two realm databases of the same realmobject from android wear to phone

Tags: android, database, merge, realm, wear-os

I'm a self taught android programmer so sorry if this is a newbie question.  Does anyone know if there's an easy way to merge two realm database files into one combined realm database?  The databases contain the same realmobject types and are mutually exclusive (no overlaps of identical objects).

My goal is this: I have a realm database of a workout "session" that is comprised of a list of objects that the user adds to using a wearable.  When the user saves the session, I want to send those saved objects to the phone where it can be combined with all past sessions in a realm database stored on the phone.

I'm able to send the database file from wear to phone as an asset and simply replace the file on the phone (using this sample code https://gist.github.com/tajchert/dc30560891bc6aee76fb), but it seems wasteful to send the entire database every time, and I don't want to lose everything if the wear database gets deleted somehow.  I'd rather save only the new data from the current session and then clear out the database on the wearable when a new session is started.  That way, I'm only ever sending new data to the wearable data layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is not possible to move Realm objects between Realms. You can use `copyFromRealm()` and `copyToRealm()`. Of course, you will need to keep track of which objects, which are already been moved (either my marking them somehow or deleting them).

Another option is to use Realm Mobile Platform (https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/) which can help you to keep all your devices in-sync.

Comment: Realm Mobile Platform sounds like the ticket!  Is the linux/mac osx requirement just to run the server? I'm using a windows pc at the moment.  Also, does this mean I no longer need to push realm files to my mobile app,  it will handle that data transfer as long as I put `syncEnabled = true` in my wear build.gradle?

Comment: Windows isn't currently supported. But you could try to install Linux in a virtual machine (docker, ...) on your Windows machine.